# A ground from a 4/4/4/6 wire and a local ground, grounding rod, in a detached building does it meet code?

Tags: electrical-panel

Can I use the ground from a 4/4/4/6 wire, that's coming from main breaker box and a local ground, a grounding rod, in a detached building and meet code. Also do both grounds get attached to grounding bar in breaker box?

Comment: What are you using the ground for? If extending the ground to a ungrounded circuit that is allowed if the load is supplied by that same panel.

Comment: This 4/4/4/6 cable is supplying 120/240V split-phase, not some sort of crazy three-phase feed, right?

Comment: pulled from the main breaker in the house to a 60 amp breaker in the garage 2 hots, 1 neutral and a ground

Comment: You can (just about) always add a ground rod to an existing grounded circuit. Whether a ground rod (other electrode) is required depends on what you are connecting it to. To a 60A main breaker in a panel then a ground rod (electrode) is required, and it attaches to the same bar as the supply.

Comment: @nosparksplease I got it Thanks

Answer (score 1):

### You have the right idea here

Pulling the four-wire feed was definitely the correct move here, as the NEC nowadays requires neutral and grounding/bonding to be provided separately to detached buildings in addition to requiring the structure to provide its own grounding electrode system.  This is because we are dealing with three different *functions* here:

- Neutral works for a living, returning normal power to your main panel and therefore to the utility
- The grounding wire provides a safety connection to return any wayward *utility* power back to the *utility* -- current flows in loops, after all, and without that grounding wire, any fault to exposed metal will become a shocking experience
- The grounding *rods*, on the other hand, are needed to return wayward *natural* electricity to terra firma -- this helps deal with voltages induced on the feeder due to lightning strikes, among other things.

And yes, both the incoming grounding wire from the feeder and the grounding electrode conductor from the outbuilding's ground rods get landed on the ground bar in the detached building's panel.  Don't forget that the panel needs to have a *main breaker* to serve as a disconnect switch for the structure, and also to provide plenty of spaces in that panel for future growth!